# Idea: "Make Me A Sammich Video" Contest

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Monthly, one of us first-page users asks (in a CW question) the community to make and upload on YouTube a video of something (not excessively) challenging and entertaining to watch (e.g., "finish [Go Beryllium](http://cokane.com/games/beryllium/)" or "score 500,000 or more in 15 minutes of [Dwarfs!](http://www.po2games.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2) arcade mode" or "Get an OCD in the Bullettin Board System in [World of Goo](http://www.worldofgoo.com/)").

Three gotchas, mostly for quality reasons:

1. The video must feature the original sound of the game.
2. The video should not add obnoxious titles or texts (youtube annotations are fine).
3. The video description must link back to the contest page.

The most *entertaining* video from those that match the requirements is awarded a bounty.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure this needs to be on the site. Unless you see using rep as reward?

Comment: @tzenes: yes. Also, the youtube video would give us "free" visibility, provided videos are high quality enough (on one hand, to show the level of awesomeness at play here) and the barrier to entry is low enough (on the other hand, so that more users can feel involved and so that there is space for the unexpected awesomeness).

Comment: Well you could host it on Meta, as to not mess with the rep, though if it's CW that wouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 5):

I think the idea of having a contest is *great*!  I just don't like the idea of awarding rep for anything beside asking and answering questions.  I think we should go with some other form of reward or recognition.

Also I agree with [Juan](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/928/idea-make-me-a-sammich-video-contest/932#932) that the blog would be a great place to host this.

Comment: I have to agree here. Considering the whole debacle on whether game recs are worth reputation, do we really need to implement a system that heavily rewards something which doesn't even require using the Q&A site as an actual Q&A site?

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be better suited in [the blog](http://gamingse.wordpress.com/), great way to publicize it also.

Comment: I am more than willing to use the blog in this manner. Though I'm not sure thats what badp intended.

Comment: Blog announcements would be great, but you'd still need the question to do the bounty and rep awarding.

Comment: If it's on youtube, don't the amount of views already give you a large enough compliment? ;-)